# What's the Razor syntax to create a table in VB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

This should not be as hard as it seems to be, but I can't for the life of me create a table in VB using Razor syntax.  The following does not work (despite what some [examples](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part3-vb) would lead me to believe):

```
<table>
@Code
   For Each item in Model
        @<tr>
            @<td>@item.DocumentType</td>
        </tr>
   Next
End Code
</table>
```

This gives me the following error:

> Parser Error Message: "<" is not valid at the start of a code block. 
>   Only identifiers, keywords, comments, and "(" are valid.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `@` before the `<td>`:

```
<table>
@Code
   For Each item in Model
        @<tr>
            <td>@item.DocumentType</td>
        </tr>
   Next
End Code
</table>
```

or a bit shorter:

```
<table>
   @For Each item in Model
        @<tr>
            <td>@item.DocumentType</td>
        </tr>
   Next
</table>
```

Once again you must remove the `@` before the `<td>`.

Comment: +1.  That worked.  So, is the idea that Razor's smart enough to find the closing </tr> itself, and treat anything inside as HTML (provided it's not "escaped" with an "@")?

Comment: @GuyBehindtheGuy, yes, Razor is smart enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
   @For Each item in Model
        @<tr><td>@item.DocumentType</td></tr>
   Next
</table>
```

See if this code snippet does what you need it to do.  This example was taken from the [ASP Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1686592.aspx/1).  I think the `@<tr>` may be what is throwing the loop off, but I have not written VB Razor (only the ASPX version of VB).  Also, I just found some [additional looping examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618477)